# Not Able to install application

Tags: swift

Install claimed to have succeeded, but application could not be found on device. bundleId = "someID"

Could not locate installed application
Domain: com.apple.platform.iphoneos
Code: -1
Recovery Suggestion: Install claimed to have succeeded, but application could not be found on device. bundleId = "someId"

--
Installed application was not present in database of installed apps after multiple lookup attempts.
Domain: com.apple.platform.iphoneos

### Code: -1

its coming mainly because of cocoa pods. can anyone please help me to resolve this.

Comment: when ever i create new project without cocoa pod app installing successfully, if i create with cocoa pods, am not able to install application in device but its working fine with simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove app, reboot device, clear derived data and the project, reboot XCode (better – macos) and install last stable release of XCode. I faced the same problem in XCode beta.

Comment: am using Xcode 11 official. i removed app, cleared Xcode derived data, Xcode memory, re installed cocoa pods, even reset mobile also. still no help.

Comment: so, do the same without reinstalling. just reboot all